# How to read weight from scale using ethernet connection

Tags: .net, vb.net, tcp, ethernet

I have a Mettler Toledo XS32000L scale and I am simply trying to read the weight via an Ethernet connection and a VB.net (2010) application. I have found plenty of information/code for a serial(COM) connection but nothing for an Ethernet connection.

Communication mode: Client & Server
Remote Host Address: 192.168.0.2.
Remote Host Port Number: 8001
Local server Port Number: 8000 (Scale IP: 192.168.0.1)

I am able to ping the scale with a reply. I have tried using a HyperTerminal but with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and hopefully this post can help many others to come. Thanks!

Other Resources

Code for a VB application with a SERIAL connection: http://control.com/thread/1240210560

Another helpful link(but not for me): 
http://vb.net-informations.com/communications/vb.net_socket_programming.htm

Comment: This is probably going to be closed FYI. While it's an interesting question, this site is focused on broken code; not general guides.

Comment: As @Carcigenicate said, please review the help page for how SO works.

Comment: I appreciate the advice - however what I would really like is some code to figure out how to do this in VB.net, so although I do not have any source code to share, I would appreciate any help on what code to write

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright - despite the criticism, I am going to post the solution after hours of researching. I created a TCP client and the modified the settings (IP, port, etc.) Hopefully this helps some future programmers!

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call Connect("192.168.0.1", "S" & vbCrLf)
End Sub

Shared Sub Connect(ByVal server As [String], ByVal message As [String])
    Try
        ' Create a TcpClient. 
        ' Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer  
        ' connected to the same address as specified by the server, port 
        ' combination. 
        Dim port As Int32 = 8000
        Dim client As New TcpClient(server, port)

        ' Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array. 
        Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)

        ' Get a client stream for reading and writing. 
        '  Stream stream = client.GetStream(); 
        Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()

        ' Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

        'Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message)
        MsgBox("Sent: {0} " & message)
        ' Receive the TcpServer.response. 
        ' Buffer to store the response bytes.
        data = New [Byte](256) {}

        ' String to store the response ASCII representation. 
        Dim responseData As [String] = [String].Empty

        ' Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes. 
        Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
        'Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData)
        MsgBox("Received: {0} " & responseData)

        ' Close everything.
        stream.Close()
        client.Close()
    Catch e As ArgumentNullException
        'Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e)
        MsgBox("ArgumentNullException: {0}" & e.Message)
    Catch e As SocketException
        'Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e)
        MsgBox("SocketException: {0}" & e.Message)
    End Try

    MsgBox("Got to this point in code")

    'Console.WriteLine(ControlChars.Cr + " Press Enter to continue...")
    'Console.Read()
End Sub 'Connect

End Class
```